# How to filter Time portion of a DateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to retrive data from table according to a particular time so I use this query below.

```
    select * from a
    where convert(smalldatetime,date,datepart(hh,date)) ='09:12:00'
```

but I get no row as result. So what should I do for my expected result?

Comment: What type is the `date` column in the `a` table?

Comment: smalldatetime


@Tim

Comment: Try select convert(smalldatetime,date,datepart(hh,date)) from a, and see the result of the convert!

Comment: Are you sure that you have row with time "09:12:00"?

Comment: @jarlh
it gives date also like   2015-12-09 09:12:00

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov 
yes i have row with '09:12:00'

Comment: So you need to find out the convert option that only returns the time part!

Comment: Try my or @Helio answer - it must work

Comment: The problem here lies with the third argument to convert(). Third argument is style argument and should not be a value calculated from the value itself. Both answers should satisfy the needs.

Comment: @gordonlinoff Can you step in and regulate this mess?

Comment: I add edit with explanation of the answer. @Helio answer is better. I used 114, which gives also ms. I corrected my answer with 108.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert directly to varchar as below

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [date], 108) = '09:12:00'
```

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov its total size is 8 :)

Comment: Correct - my fault :)

Comment: can you explain me why you convert it into 108 format and also explain me why my query not show any result and according to your query i i get my expected result?

Comment: @davidsam refer to this article: Remarks > Date and Time Styles > 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=en-US&k=k(CONVERT_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [DATE],108) = '09:12:00'
```

Your datatype is already `smalldatetime` so you have to convert to `varchar` and compare with string.

**EDIT:**

Answer explanation:

You have `smalldatetime` inside [DATE] column. For example `2015-10-01 09:12:00`. To compare only time you need to convert to string which contains only time. For this reason you will use command [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) from TSQL.

It will convert `smalldatetime` to 8 characters string. As a result you will have `09:12:00` and then you compare it with your string.

Comment: 108 is the direct conversion type

Comment: 10x, @Helio. I don't know for that option.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov please explain your answer that why you convert into 108 and why my query not working but your works properly?

Answer (score 1):

In Sql server 2008 you can convert to TIME. By specifying TIME(0) you have the desired format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
WHERE CAST(date as time(0)) ='09:12:00'
```

Comment: error:

Msg 1001, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Line 4: Length or precision specification 0 is invalid.

Comment: That indicates that you are running a different compatibility mode than 2008. Test link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3691/0)

Answer (score 0):

//CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8),[columnName],108) = '09:12:00'
```